# I was using Broadcast Receiver to get notification data even app is killed, i want same fuctionality in flutter,

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map message) async {

```
  print("onMessage Called.. $message");
},
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
);
```

// cant get data in onBackgroundMessage after 15 min of app inactivity

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Please show us which Firebase packages you're using, and your implementation. Your manifest will be helpful too.

Comment: you can write android and ios code directly if none of the packages on pub.dev serve your desires , see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab